# UIImageView mask layer is white

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uiimageview, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a round corner on a UIImageView on only one specified corner for the top row in a UITableView and the bottom row.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I have:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:user.image];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImageWoman.jpg"]];
[url release];

if (indexPath.row == 0)
    cell.imageView.layer.mask = [Helper roundedCornerOnImage:cell.imageView onCorner:UIRectCornerTopLeft];
else if (indexPath.row == self.arrayIntrestedPeople.count - 1)
    cell.imageView.layer.mask = [Helper roundedCornerOnImage:cell.imageView onCorner:UIRectCornerBottomLeft];
```

My roundedCornerOnImage method:

```
+ (CAShapeLayer *) roundedCornerOnImage: (UIImageView *)imageView onCorner: (UIRectCorner)rectCorner
{
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageView.bounds 
                                                   byRoundingCorners:rectCorner
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.frame = imageView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;


    //Don't add masks to layers already in the hierarchy!
    UIView *superview = [imageView superview];
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    [superview addSubview:imageView];


    return maskLayer;
}
```

Now, when the UITableView is loaded, all the images are perfeclty loaded, but not the top nor the bottom image in which I have applied a layer mask. It's **white**, the image is totally **white**.

When I scroll the UITableView so the cells can be recreated the images included the top and bottom image of the UITableView **is shown**.

Why is this?

My hole code in cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVieww cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    GlobalProperties *gp = [GlobalProperties sharedGlobalProperties];
    User *user = [self.arrayIntrestedPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    SizeableRoundedTableViewImage *cell = (SizeableRoundedTableViewImage *)[tableVieww dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[SizeableRoundedTableViewImage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:user.image];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImageWoman.jpg"]];
    [url release];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.imageView.layer.mask = [Helper roundedCornerOnImage:cell.imageView onCorner:UIRectCornerTopLeft];
    else if (indexPath.row == self.arrayIntrestedPeople.count - 1)
        cell.imageView.layer.mask = [Helper roundedCornerOnImage:cell.imageView onCorner:UIRectCornerBottomLeft];


        cell.textLabel.text                 = user.username;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the mask without removing it from the superview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the real solution, but it looks like you are assigning the mask property twice.  You set it within `-roundedCornerOnImage:onCorner:`, but that also returns the mask, and you are setting it again with the return value.  This might be the "undefined results" mentioned in the documentation.

My suggestion would be to get rid of the `cell.imageView.layer.mask =` bits of each call.

As a secondary note, it may be prudent to keep track of the index of the `UIImageView` before removing it and inserting it back into place rather than putting it on top of everything.  Just in case.